# What do brackets inside brackets mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
oTable.fnSort([[columnIndex, 'asc']]);
```

Can someone explain to me what the ([[]]) means. I have never seen brackets inside of brackets before.

Comment: It's just an array with another array as its first element.

Comment: Presumably the parameter is in this format to support sorting on multiple columns, e.g. oTable.fnSort([[columnIndex1, 'asc'], [columnIndex2, 'desc']])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are notation for a JavaScript array. This code means that the argument to the function is an array that contains one element, which is an array itself.

An array with two elements:

```
[columnIndex, 'asc']
```

An array with one element, which is an array that contains two elements:

```
[[columnIndex, 'asc']]
```

Answer (score 4):

You're passing an array to the `fnSort` method. That array contains one element, which happens to be another array, with two elements:

```
[] // An empty array
[[]] // An array with one element (an empty array)
[[columnIndex, "asc"]] // An array with one element (an array with 2 elements)
```

This is known as *array literal* syntax, which is generally preferred to the alternative (the `Array` constructor).